# Remap Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V to Super+C and Super+V

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, remapping

It sounds like it should be a trivial task to do, but nope.. it's easy to find very different answers to this question, that involve lengthy configuration change and get nothing.

Is there a simple solution?

- I use Unity
- Do not want to remap <kbd>Super</kbd> key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key :(

Comment: This should be a feature in the next distro.